# How to flatten IO (IO ())?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm just learning Haskell and monad transformers and I've found myself with an IO (IO ()) that I'd like to flatten into just IO (). I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, but can't pinpoint exactly where I'm getting lost.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. This is a convoluted way of implementing `echo`, but it illustrates the problem.

```
userInput :: Monad m => ReaderT (IO String) m (IO String)
userInput = ask

echo :: Monad m => ReaderT (IO String) m (IO ())
echo = userInput >>= \input ->  -- unwrap ReaderT to get an IO String
         input >>= (\s ->       -- unwrap IO String to get a String
           putStrLn s)          -- print out the String
         & return               -- rewrap into a ReaderT

main :: IO (IO ())              -- How to turn IO (IO ()) to IO ()?
main = runReaderT echo getLine
```

In my real application, I have a [Spock](https://www.spock.li/) app that makes HTTP requests to an upstream server. Spock apps use a monad transformer stack called `SpockCtxT` and I'd like to insert a `ReaderT` into the stack to abstract the HTTP request so that I can swap it out for a mock implementation in my tests.

Fundamentally, the idea is a monad transformer stack where one of the transformers gives you an `IO` whether it be an HTTP request or `getLine`. Am I thinking about this incorrectly or is there some way to do this?

Comment: Use `join` to flatten.

Comment: `IO (IO ()) -> IO ()` is `join` from Control.Monad

Comment: Side note: when libraries export things with types like `IO (IO ())` they generally don't expect you to use `join` but rather something like `layeredAction >>= \inner -> somethingElse >> inner`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to the question as asked is `join :: IO (IO ()) -> IO ()`. But the answer to the question I think you *should* have asked is `liftIO :: IO () -> ReaderT (IO String) IO ()`. Like this:

```
userInput :: MonadIO m => ReaderT (IO String) m String
userInput = ask >>= liftIO -- this liftIO eliminates your need for join

echo :: MonadIO m => ReaderT (IO String) m ()
echo = userInput >>= liftIO . putStrLn -- this liftIO is just so you can use putStrLn in ReaderT

main :: IO ()
main = runReaderT echo getLine
```

Building monadic actions that return monadic actions, and then manually combining the inner actions, is in *most* cases ignoring the whole point of monad transformers. Instead of having two layers of monadic actions, you should have a single layer which has a transformer version of the outer action on top of the inner action -- that is, instead of working with `ReaderT r Foo (IO a)` actions, which require manual binds for both the `ReaderT r Foo` layer and the `IO` layer, you should be working with `ReaderT r (FooT IO) a` actions, where just one binding handles the reader, foo, and IO effects at once.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much! I'd upvote you twice if I could.

Answer (score 13):

Use `join`. It has the type signature

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

which specializes to

```
join :: IO (IO ()) -> IO ()
```

you can use [hoogle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hoogle) to find this out. It is a command-line tool. We can search by type signature:

```
hoogle "IO (IO ()) -> IO ()"
```

gives

```
Control.Monad join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
Control.Composition (.$) :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
RIO join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
Universum.Monad.Reexport join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
Stack.Prelude join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
Relude.Monad.Reexport join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
Intro join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
Hledger.Web.Import join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
Data.Edison.Seq concat :: Sequence s => s (s a) -> s a
Data.Edison.Seq.Defaults concatUsingFoldr :: Sequence s => s (s a) -> s a
-- plus more results not shown, pass --count=20 to see more
```

which has several functions that are exactly what you want.

Comment: Hoogle also has a website: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ (or https://hoogle.haskell.org/ for the latest, alpha, version). You can also use the Hoogle search integrated into Stackage, accessible through the search bar at https://www.stackage.org/. And finally, you can also use [Hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/), an alternative to Hoogle, if you're having trouble finding something.