# Is it possible to use typeclasses to change `ReaderT (IO a) IO a` into `ReaderT (i a) IO a`?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, monads, typeclass, monad-transformers

I'm learning Haskell and I've got the following code thanks to help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939191/how-to-flatten-io-io/53939660#53939660), which is just an `echo` program. It works great, but I want to make some improvements to it and am running into trouble.

```
userInput :: MonadIO m => ReaderT (IO String) m String
userInput = ask >>= liftIO -- this liftIO eliminates your need for join

echo :: MonadIO m => ReaderT (IO String) m ()
echo = userInput >>= liftIO . putStrLn -- this liftIO is just so you can use putStrLn in ReaderT

main :: IO ()
main = runReaderT echo getLine
```

What I'd like to do is change `ReaderT (IO String)` to `ReaderT (i String)` and make it more general so I can swap it out for unit testing. The problem is, because we use `liftIO` inside `userInput` it sort of *ties* `i` together with `IO`. Is there some way to replace `liftIO` with something else to make the following code work?

```
class Monad i => MonadHttp i where
  hole :: MonadIO m => i a -> ReaderT (i a) m a

instance MonadHttp IO where
  hole = liftIO

newtype MockServer m a = MockServer
  { server :: ReaderT (String) m a }
  deriving (Applicative, Functor, Monad, MonadTrans)

instance MonadIO m => MonadHttp (MockServer m) where
  -- MockServer m a -> ReaderT (MockServer m a) m1 a
  hole s = s -- What goes here?

userInput :: (MonadHttp i, MonadIO m) => ReaderT (i String) m String
userInput = ask >>= hole

echo :: (MonadHttp i, MonadIO m) => ReaderT (i String) m ()
echo = userInput >>= \input ->
         ((I.liftIO . putStrLn) input)

main = runReaderT echo (return "hello" :: MockServer IO String)
```

Comment: `MonadIO` is a class of monads in which `IO` computations can be embedded. `liftIO` does just that: lifts an `IO` computation to your `MonadIO`. If you want to replace `IO` with something more general, you also need to replace `MonadIO` with something more general.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think the part I'm confused about is that I don't actually want to change `m` which is an `IO` in this case. I want to change `i` which is *also* an `IO`. But `m` is the `MonadIO`, not `i`. I think there's something here I am missing.

Comment: Why does the mock need to be a `ReaderT String IO`, instead of just `IO`?

Comment: I was just following this post: https://making.pusher.com/unit-testing-io-in-haskell/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that [`ReaderT r m a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#t:ReaderT) is a `newtype` wrapper for `r -> m a`. Specifically, `MonadIO m => ReaderT (IO a) m b` is equivalent to `MonadIO m => IO a -> m b`. So let me rephrase your question:

> Can you convert `MonadIO m => IO a -> m b` to `MonadIO m => m a -> m b`?

The answer is **no**, because the `IO a` appears as an *input* to the function type. (Sometimes you'll see people say "in negative position", which roughly means the same as "input".) The important thing here is that converting function inputs works in the opposite direction to converting function outputs.

---

Let's take a step back and think about a more general case. If you have a function `a -> b` and you want to convert its output to get a function `a -> c`, you need to be able to convert `b`s into `c`s. If you can give me a function which converts `b`s into `c`s, I can apply that to values after they come out of the `a -> b` function.

```
convertOutput :: (b -> c)  -- the converter function
              -> (a -> b)  -- the function to convert
              -> (a -> c)  -- the resulting converted function
convertOutput f g = \x -> f (g x)
```

`convertOutput` is better known as `(.)`.

Converting a function's input works the opposite way. If you want to convert a function `b -> a` into a function `c -> a`, you have to convert `c`s into `b`s. If you can give me a function which converts `c`s into `b`s, I can apply that to values before they go in to the `b -> a` function.

```
convertInput :: (c -> b)  -- the converter function
             -> (b -> a)  -- the function to convert
             -> (c -> a)  -- the resulting converted function
convertInput f g = \x -> g (f x)
```

(Occasionally you'll hear the words *covariance* and *contravariance* in connection with the idea of converting types. They refer to the idea that that converter functions can go in one of two directions. Functions are covariant in their output parameters and contravariant in their inputs.)

---

Back to the question,

> Can you convert `MonadIO m => IO a -> m b` to `MonadIO m => m a -> m b`?

Hopefully you can see that this question is really asking for a way to turn an `m a` into `IO a`. (You have to turn the `m a` into an `IO a` in order to feed it to the original function.) `MonadIO` contains a single method, `liftIO :: IO a -> m a`, which embeds an `IO` computation into a "bigger" monad which may contain other effects, but that's quite the opposite of what we need. There's no going the other way.

Nor should there be. `m a` here is a monadic computation which may perform all manner of unknown effects. You can't turn an arbitrary monadic value into an `IO` without knowing what the effects are. And many (most) monadic effects don't have a straightforward translation into an `IO` computation; running a `State` computation, for example, requires a starting value for the state.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the detailed and easy to understand answer! Since this approach isn't possible, would you happen to have a recommendation for how you would mock the user input for unit testing?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do! If you just want to supply some canned input, you can give `return "myCannedInput"` as the reader's `IO String` argument. If you need the input to change each time the action is executed you'll have to do it imperatively, by building a state machine on top of an [`IORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html).